# LOCAL and GLOBAL Functions in C

Tags: c

I'm rooting around some really old C code and have come across the following:

```
GLOBAL void Input_Channels()
{
    // removed
}
```

There are also plenty of similar, but LOCAL.

What is this? I can't see any information anywhere about the LOCAL / GLOBAL function.

Comment: Might be some kind of a macro (maybe just for help locating the function in a quick search). Have you searched the entire project for the definition?

Comment: _Really old_ How old is it? What compiler? Platform?

Comment: well, not really really old. From 2000, so 16 years old. It turns out it was a macro and I had overlooked that possibility. Found it in a header file.

Comment: This would be why it is a really bad idea to re-invent the C language and replace it with your own "secret macro language". Nobody knows what the code does. Qualified guess: GLOBAL is either an empty macro or `extern`, LOCAL is `static`.

Comment: You are 100% correct, GLOBAL is empty and LOCAL is static. Could you help me understand why? I cannot figure out the logic behind this. @Lundin

Comment: @MHartley Whoever wrote it thought they were smart... it is all related to scope of the functions. Functions, just like variables have a scope where they are visible. `static` limits the scope to the current translation unit.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I unfortunately don't have a choice and have to work with this existing code. I'll have to spend some time understanding the macros as there are a large amount of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that somewhere there are macros defined for this, to help you see whether the functions should be considered public or private (to use object-oriented lingo) - or whether the function is exported or not.

GLOBAL could do nothing where LOCAL could mark the functions static.

I haven't seen that before, so maybe it is an obscure addition to the syntax used by the compiler vendor. Which compiler are you using ?

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. It's a macro. Had me quite confused, I have never used macros in front of functions before and took me completely by surprise.

Comment: @MHartley You're welcome :) I've seen something similar used on function arguments (especially pointer values): INPUT and OUTPUT in front of the variable, to indicate if the function read or writes from the variable in the parameter-list.